# Unity Firebase Messaging

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I only have one question, is it possible to **unsubscribe** FCM topic when app is kill or exit ? I tried the script below, it didn't work.

```
void OnApplicationQuit(){
    Firebase.Messaging.FirebaseMessaging.Unsubscribe(topicname);
}
```

Comment: You have to define "not working"....Did you put `Debug.Log` in the `OnApplicationQuit` function? If so, is that getting called at-all?

Comment: @Programmer firebase only can run in app, try in unity editor will no have any result

Comment: You can use PlayerPrefs to write random value in the OnApplicationQuit function then try to read it next time you open the app. That's one way to do this.